# Gaining Hidden Ability through GTS?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In Pokemon XY, I want one of my Pokemon to have its hidden ability. If I put it up on the GTS, and have my friend trade me for it, then trade it back to me, will it gain its hidden ability?

Bulbapedia says: "Where possible, all Pokémon obtained from the Pokémon Global Link, either via the Pokémon Dream World or a Global Link promotion, will always have their Hidden Ability."

Does this apply to gen VI?

Comment: It *does* say, specifically, Pokemon obtained from the Dream World or a promotion. So I don't think (and I seriously doubt) this means the GTS.

Comment: Oh bummer, the GTS doesn't count as the Global link? This is my first pokemon game in a while so I thought they might have been synonymous.

Comment: Also I noticed my friends have a Greninja with its hidden ability. How would they obtain this? The only way they could have gotten that pokemon is from the GTS as it wasn't their starter pokemon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Global Link" is just Nintendo's term that encompasses all their online services (including the [Global Link Website](http://en.pokemon-gl.com/)), which includes but isn't limited to Wonder Trade, GTS and the Pokémon Dream World. In other words, every time you read "Global Link", they simply mean 'online'.

The Bulbapedia quote says it all:

> "Where possible, all Pokémon obtained <strike>from the Pokémon Global Link</strike> online, **either via the Pokémon Dream World or a Global Link promotion**, will always have their Hidden Ability."

So unfortunately no, trading with your friend over GTS isn't going to get you the hidden ability.

However, if someone puts up a Pokemon on the GTS **already with** the Hidden Ability, and you trade them for it, then you will get the Hidden Ability. This is most likely how your friend got his/her Greninja with its Hidden Ability (unless someone was very kind and put it through Wonder Trade).

---

### A brief overview of Abilities:

Abilities in general (not just Hidden ones) are generated when the Pokemon is first encountered. this means either

- In the wild,
- Hatching from an egg ([passed on by the mother or the father](http://www.serebii.net/xy/breeding.shtml) when breeding with Ditto), or
- When evolving, If the pre-evolved form had it's hidden ability, then the evolved form will as well.

In other words, there is no way to change a Pokemon's ability via trading. (Caveat, unless there's a Pokemon that evolves when trading, and it's evolved form has different Abilities, although I cannot think of any)

**So I can catch wild Pokemon with Hidden Abilities?**

Only in Horde battles, and even then only rarely. Plus the types of Pokemon that appear in horde battles are few in number, and doesn't include Froakie or any other starter line at all.

**So why does everyone have Hidden Abilities online?**

Everyone wants Hidden Abilities as they are generally better than the Stock abilities (although this isn't always the case). Either way, there's the stigma attached to them: Because they are 'rarer', they must be 'better'. Everyone is therefore striving to get them, and that's why you see so many of them.

**So where can I get Pokemon with Hidden Abilities?**

As Unionhawk states, [Friend Safari](http://www.serebii.net/xy/friendsafari.shtml) is your best bet. You'll need a friend of the right type (Water for Frogadier), and then Frogadier can appear in Slot 3, possibly with it's hidden ability.

---

**Side note**: One way I've found extremely helpful to check a Pokemon's ability in battle is by using the move [Worry Seed](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Worry_Seed_%28move%29), which Budew learns. Worry Seed will change the targets Ability (in battle only) to Insomnia, but before it does, it will flash up the Pokemon's Ability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do many of the greninjas I see online have their hidden ability? And by what it says on bulbapedia, pokemon can only have their hidden ability from online, so how could they put their pokemon with the hidden ability up?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Abilities work. Abilities are generated when the Pokemon is first encountered, either in the wild, hatching from an egg (passed on by the mother) or upon evolving, if the pre-evolved form had it's hidden ability, then the evolved form will as well. There is no way to change a Pokemon's ability via trading

Comment: As for why there are so many Hidden Abilities online, because everyone wants Hidden Abilities as they are generally better than the stock abilities (although this isn't always the case). either way, there's the stigma attached to them that they are better because they are rarer

Comment: @KevinDuke You can get the hidden ability from pokemon obtained in the Friend Safari as well, and by other methods. So a Hidden Ability Greninja can be obtained by evolving a Friend Safari Frogadier. [Check this forum post out](http://pokemonshowdown.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2875&sid=21ab24f53b8656afb5dea83f89a79699) for a list.

Comment: @Robo But it states that hidden abilities are only generated when certain extreme cases are met. So there's no way it can be generated when encountered in the wild (except horde but greninja isn't in a horde) or from eggs

Comment: @KevinDuke - I'm talking about abilities in general, not just hidden ones

Comment: Yeah, but my question said hidden ability right on it, I know how regular abilities work

Comment: @KevinDuke - I apologise then, you made out in your comment above that you didn't understand how Abilities could/couldn't be changed. Which is why I added all that extra info. In either case I've edited the sentence there to make it clearer that I'm talking about Abilities in general (at least until I get down to the Hidden abilities section :))

Comment: Don't worry :) Thanks for all your effort! I appreciate it

Comment: @KevinDuke - No problem. Glad I could help :)